# PHP/Laravel get rows with certain column values

Tags: php, laravel, recordset

As can be seen in the linked image, I want to query the records that have the same chapter number (skipping the zeros). Let's say I have 50 chapters, so the query will yield 50 sets, each set corresponding to certain column value i.e. chapter number.

[image: data table with the same chapter numbers]

How can I limit the query to that in my Laravel controller?

Comment: The same known chapter number or more of a group by chapter number kind of deal?

Comment: You database is designed poorly. It seems to me that when you set chapter to `0` you are intending for that to be a chapter heading. I think you need a table for ChapterHeading that the Chapter models can link to in a `belongsTo` relatioship.

Comment: @JustCarty Yes, you are right. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @apokryfos I want to get groups, just like drawn in the image.

Comment: I thought so. This is designed badly, because _how_ do you know that ID 1 is chapter 1, and ID 9 is chapter 2? Without looking at everything, or selecting all chapter 0, and grabbing the `n` from the list, it's tricky. Please consider utilising the nature of a relational database.

Comment: I've written an answer based on my views from the comments above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67785574/3578036

Answer (score 2):

Get chapter groups, Like drawing in the image

```
$chapters = Translation::where('chapter', '!=', 0)->get()->groupBy('chapter');
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken this returns a collection. It is not a query and it's not paginateable. What do you recommend in that case?

Comment: please check this solution for pagination
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67784879/16045221

Answer (score 1):

Without pagination:

```
$chapters = Translation::where('chapter', '!=', 0)->get()->groupBy('chapter');
```

With pagination :

```
$posts = Translation::where('chapter', '!=', 0)->orderBy('chapter', 'ASC')->paginate($request->get('per_page', 2));
$grouped_by_chapter = $posts->mapToGroups(function ($post) {
    return [$post->chapter => $post];
});
$posts_by_chapter = $posts->setCollection($grouped_by_chapter);
```

for more: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your project setup, I'd say:

```php
$chapters = DB::table('translations')
    ->select('chapter')
    ->distinct()
    ->where('chapter', '<>', 0)
    ->get();
```

If you use eloquent models:

```
$chapters = Translations::get()
    ->pluck('chapter')
    ->flatten()
    ->filter()
    ->values()
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Translation` model and want to use `Eloquent`:

```php
$chapters = Translation::where('chapter', '!=', 0)->get()->groupBy('chapter');
```

The above says get all `Translation` where the `Chapter` they are associated to is not `Chapter` `zero` and group all translations by the `chapter` column. So if you have `50` chapters you'll have `50` collections each with their translations contained within.

If you just want specific columns, you can use `select()` and provide it with only the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the Elequent model, you can create a hasMany relation to 'translations',

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
    public function translations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Translation::class, 'chapter');
    }
```

and then retrieve the 'Chapter' models with translations.

```
$chapters = Chapter::with('translations')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these answers are correct, but I thought I'd offer a different approach.

## 1. Create a new table

Consider creating an additional table called `chapters`.
Do this by using the command:

```sh
php artisan make:model Chapter -m
```

This'll create a model and migration.
The migration will look like this:

```php
Schema::create('chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('number')->unsigned();
    $table->string('heading');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

## 2. Add the foreign key to your old table

Then modify your model from your screenshot. From here on, I'll assume the same as everyone else, that this table is called `translation`, with a model called `Transaltion`.
Your new migration should look like this:

```php
Schema::create('translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('chapters_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('translation');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

## 3. Add the relationship to the models

`Translation` model

```php
public function chapters()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Chapter::class);
}
```

`Chapter` model

```php
public function translations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Translation::class);
}
```

## 4. Using the new relationship

Instead of having to use `groupBy`, or any of the other methods, you now can query on each heading.
An example of some of those below.

### 4.1 How many chapters do we have?

```php
Chapter::count();
```

### 4.2 How many sentences are there in Chapter 1?

```php
Chapter::where('number', 1)->translations()->count();
// or if you want to get a Collection of them
Chapter::where('number', 1)->translations;
// or if you just want a certain few columns
Chapter::where('number', 1)->translations()->select('translation', 'sentence')->get();
```

### 4.3 How do I get all chapters and corresponding translations?

```php
$chapters = Chapter::with('translations')->get();
```

Then in your blade view, do:

```php
@foreach ($chapters as $chapter)
    <h1>{{ $chapter->heading }}</h1>

    <p>Sentences:</p>
    @foreach ($chapter->translations as $sentence)
        <p>{{ $sentence }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Alistair No problem, I thought I'd just write it up. Whether you want to change your database or not - that's fine - but this might be useful for others that find this. Relational databases are really useful when used properly.